# Using this (the one being clicked ) with VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I am learning vueJS and have 2 clickable divs that share the same method. So when I click one of the divs the action happens for both of them.

What is the best way to action an @click on a div (This div) the one that is being clicked.

So I'm trying to open and close a menu only on the one (div) that is being clicked.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="mainbox-wrapper">
      <div class="mainbox">text</div>
      <div class="selectbox" @click="actionMenu" id="foo" ref="foo">select box</div>
      <div class="menu" v-show="isShow">select box</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="mainbox-wrapper">
      <div class="mainbox">text</div>
      <div class="selectbox" @click="actionMenu" id="bar" ref="bar">select box</div>
      <div class="menu" v-show="isShow">select box</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
  methods:{
    actionMenu(event){
      let targetId = event.currentTarget.id;
      this.isShow = !this.isShow;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `v-show` directive, you can toggle class for the relevant div:

```
actionMenu(event){
   event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('d-none');
}
```

`d-none` class is applicable for bootstrap 4. If you are using it, then it's great but if you're not using, then you can add your own class.

```
.d-none {
  display: none; /* bootstrap uses !important as well */
  /* if you wish, you can add !important */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather use v-on than @click,
you can learn more about HTML listeners [here](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/events.html)

Your HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="mainbox-wrapper">
   <div class="mainbox">text</div>
      <div class="selectbox" v-on="click: onClick" id="foo" ref="foo">select box</div>         
  </div>
</div>
```

and in your js

```
methods: {
        onClick: function (e) {
          console.log(e.currentTarget.id;)
          }
    }
```

Comment: How do I bind this to the div or button which is being clicked though?

Comment: in the HTML you specify which method you want to call. in my example, `v-on="click: <anyMethodName> "`